# How to delete the parse class i.e., entire table from parse cloud in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Help in coding dynamically to delete parse table or parse class.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show that code. + all about this is given at Parse.com's docs. Have you seen them?

Comment: Why do you want to delete parse table or/and classes. Could you provide more description about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Like I was trying to form the table which consist of user selected cricket players. But if user does not the team, he should be able to delete it. This is what I want to accomplish? Provide any more suggestion please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it says in the Documentation, you have to query it then call:

```
yourObjectHere.deleteInBackground();
```

Furthermore I'm not sure about the code, but you can delete them online. If you want to delete a class, Click on your class you want to delete, then click on More then Drop Class. It will tell you to enter the name of the class and it will be deleted.

Currently I don't think there is a way you can delete a class using code. It has to be done via the Databrowser online. [Cant delete via code - has to be done via Databrowser.](http://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-drop-a-class-programmatically))

Comment: I was to establish in deleting the rows from the tabl using the document but what about entire class to be deleted from the parse.